# How to put the query in MySQL using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I put this query in my PHP code

```
SET @prev_value = NULL;
SET @rank_count = 0;
SELECT implement_id, total_implement, percent,CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = percent THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := percent THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
END AS rank
FROM goal_implement 
ORDER BY implement_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This is because you are using multiple lines for the query. If you want to do this make `string concatenation using dot operator`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT implement_id, total_implement, percent,CASE
    WHEN @prev_value = percent THEN @rank_count
    WHEN @prev_value := percent THEN @rank_count := @rank_count + 1
END AS rank
FROM goal_implement 
ORDER BY implement_id DESC LIMIT 1");

$result = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

?>
```

Comment: error message "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @rank_count = 0; SELECT implement_id, total_implement, percent,CASE WH' at line 2"

Comment: I just want to display every users rank in a page.... the query works on sql... but in php code, show an error

Comment: This is because you are using multiple lines for the query. If you want to do this make `string concatenation using dot operator`